# Fetch All CKRecords of certain type

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Let's say I have records of type `A` in the private CloudKit database. How do I fetch *ALL* records of that type, without specifying record IDs or a query predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKQuery requires a non-nil predicate on initialization ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014043-CH1-SW2)), so you have to specify a predicate, even if it's always true. Ex:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "TheRecordType", predicate: predicate)

let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.queryCompletionBlock = {cursor, error in
    // done
}

CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase.addOperation(operation)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the thing I was going to try next since there seems to be no other way to properly do this. It seems kind of weird though, so I thought there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: @ErikAigner My initial thought as well, but there shouldn't be any issues if this was the way it was designed to work. Just as a note, if you use a predicate like this when creating a subscription, on the server, it maps as "blankness" in the subscription's criteria field.